# Find controls in listview item template of the same type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, listview

I am working on claim expenses application for the staff where I work.  Part of the process contains a listview, part of a new requirement is that if an expense type is mileage the user will not be able to edit the item, only delete and resubmit as part of business rules and UK tax reasons etc.

Anyway, I want to be able to find a control in each item of the listview that has a certain text value.

I thought something like the following but this is not correct and I know why.

```
        Label ExpenseTypeLabel = (Label)Expenses.FindControl("ExpenseTypeLabel");
        string ExpenseType = (ExpenseTypeLabel.Text.ToString());

        if (ExpenseType == "Mileage")
        {
            foreach (ListViewDataItem thisItem in Expenses.Items)
            {

                ImageButton btnEdit = (ImageButton)thisItem.FindControl("btnEdit");
                btnEdit.Enabled = false;


            }
        }
```

The expenses are based on weekending and as the page loads it throws my excepion as It cannot bind to a particular individual control as there are many ExpenseTypeLabels associated with the expense for the current weekending (which loads first).

What I am trying to accomplish here is to find all ExpenseTypeLabels in both the item template and the alternating item template and disable the edit function of that expense item.  FYI incase you're wondering the weekending is the expense, and the children are the individual expense items.

Could one of you lovely people please educate me on the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use OnItemDataBound event as follows

```
OnItemDataBound="Expenses_ItemDataBound"

protected void Expenses_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {

        Label ExpenseTypeLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("ExpenseTypeLabel");

        string ExpenseType = (ExpenseTypeLabel.Text.ToString());

        if (ExpenseType == "Mileage")
        {
            // disable button
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that kinda put me on the right track I think, it does not 'fully' meet my requirement however It give me a better understanding

Comment: You can have the answer :-) I could not diable the button fro some reason, I could only se the visible property to false which i find strange!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Binding order, and timing for accessing bound items, is extremely important; this is especially true when you have sub controls that have binding items also.

If you want to affect the the display for these bound controls, you can usually do it from the aspx end.

Create a link from the front end to a function on the server end, then pass it all the necessary parameters:

```
<asp:listview id='lstExpense'>
   ...
   <asp:button id='btnEdit' enabled='<%#= isEnabled(((Expense)Container.DataItem).ExpenseType) %>' ...
   ...
<asp:listview>
```

On the server end, make a public function to return that value:

```
public boolean IsEnabled(string ExpenseType) {
    return ('Mileage' != ExpenseType);
}
```

---

Best solution though, is to use jQuery.  Not exaggerating, but you can accomplish all of that with something as simple as:

```
$('.rowClass').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.expenseTypeClass').val() == 'Mileage')) 
        $(this).find('.btnEditClass').attr('disabled','disabled');
})
```

Comment: That's good input thanks, I have been advised by my manager to avoid using any client side scripting other than AJAX as it's managed code.  I expect that jQuery will have to be learned at some point soon as many of the questions I have asked myself could be done easily with some kind of JS/jQ